# How to cast JSTL variable to string in Liferay JSP?

Tags: jsp, jstl, liferay

I habe a problem with my latest Liferay Portlet or rather a JSP I'm using in this portlet.
I am using a string array that contains strings which are shown on the page with a delete-button. Each of these buttons calls an actionURL to submit the selected data to another function.
Maybe it's easier to understand what I want to do by just looking at my example code:

```
<c:forEach var="name" items="<%=myNames %>">    
    <liferay-portlet:actionURL name="deleteName" var="${name}">
        <liferay-portlet:param name="myName" value="${name}" />
    </liferay-portlet:actionURL>    
    <c:out value="${name}" />
    <liferay-ui:icon-delete label="<%= true %>" url="${name}"/> 
</c:forEach>
```

Maybe you already noticed what my problem is: the var-attribute in the actionURL has to be a string. That's why this example doesn't work.
My question is now: how can I cast my $name variable dynamically to set it int the actionURL and later call it with the icon?

Thank you.

Comment: Is that an off-the-top example or the *actual* code? The `items="<%=myNames%>"` would not ever work in `c:forEach`. Basically, you're passing `String.valueOf(myNames)` to `items` attribute, not a fullworthy `List<String>` or `String[]`, so `c:forEach` wouldn't ever be able to iterate over it. Do not mix scriptlets with EL. Use EL only.

Comment: Well, good to know that this doesn't work, because it is displayed correctly and as expected. ;) And I don't know an alternative to define actionURLs in Liferay just with EL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
names.add("me");
names.add("myself");
names.add("I");

pageContext.setAttribute("names", names);
%>

<c:forEach var="name" items="${names}">
    <portlet:actionURL var="deleteURL">
        <portlet:param name="myName" value="${name}" />
    </portlet:actionURL>

    <liferay-ui:icon-delete label="<%= true %>" url="${deleteURL}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Does this work for you?